# Scaling heatmaps of different sizes

Tags: r, visualization

I have several square matrices containing correlations, but of very different sizes (ranging from 300 rows/columns, to 3000 rows/columns). For example, two of them could be:

```
small_matrix <- replicate(10, rnorm(10)) 
large_matrix <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))
```

However, if you make a heatmap of these, they will be difficult to compare:

```
heatmap(small_matrix, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, labRow = NA, labCol = NA)
heatmap(large_matrix, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, labRow = NA, labCol = NA)
```

I want to make the visualizations comparable, at least on an "impressionistic" level. Therefore, I want to rescale them, so that they are all, say 10 rows/columns large. That way you can at least get make a visual, impressionistic, comparison of the matrices.

Probably this would entail somehow dividing each matrix in 10x10 submatrices, and then taking the average of each submatrix.

What would be a good approach to doing this?

Comment: I think that is an interesting idea, but the implied reordering of rows and columns could make interpretations difficult. Maybe you might use some information from both dendrograms to identify submatrices that would be suitable for aggregation (e.g. with `cutree()`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do some interpolating(but it will be weaker as taking averages) using ggplot2 (also you need reshape, for melt function)

```
p1 <- qplot(X1, X2, data = melt(small_matrix), fill = value, geom = "raster")
p2 <- qplot(X1, X2, data = melt(large_matrix), fill = value, geom = "raster")
p3 <- qplot(X1, X2, data = melt(small_matrix), fill = value, geom = "raster",interpolate = TRUE)
p4 <- qplot(X1, X2, data = melt(large_matrix), fill = value, geom = "raster",interpolate = TRUE)

p <- grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `raster` library:

```
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)

large_matrix <- replicate(100, rnorm(100)) 
matrix_rasterized <- raster(large_matrix)

extent(matrix_rasterized) <- extent(c(-180, 180, -90, 90))
size <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
matrix_resampled <- resample(matrix_rasterized, size)
matrix_rescaled <- as.matrix(matrix_resampled)

greyscale <- brewer.pal(9, "Greys")

heatmap(matrix_rescaled, labRow = NA, labCol = NA, 
main = "Large matrix - Rescaled", col = greyscale)
```

[image]